# Doctrine with Code Igniter - Unable to save ManyToOne

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine

I'm trying to integrate Code Igniter with Doctrine 2. Everything runs well except that I'm unable to save a property of one object.

Here a little code snippet that throws a strange error

```
$account = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\Account')->findOneById($accountId);

$ofx = new \Entities\FinancialRecord();
$a = $accountCatDao->findByPayeeName("PETROCAN", $account);

ofx->setAccount($account);
$ofx->setAmount($b->getAmount());
$ofx->setDatePosted(new DateTime());
$ofx->setDateUser(new DateTime());
$ofx->setPayeeCity($b->getPayeeCity());
$ofx->setPayeeName($b->getPayeeName());
$ofx->setPayeeState($b->getPayeeState());
$ofx->setTransactionId($b->getTransactionId());
$ofx->setTransactionType($b->getTransactionType());

// FOLLOWING LINE CAUSING THE PROBLEM
$ofx->setCategory($a->getCategory());

$this->em->persist($ofx);
$this->em->flush();
```

**Error Thrown**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'No mapping file found named 'Proxies.__CG__.Entities.Category.dcm.yml' for class 'Proxies\__CG__\Entities\Category'.' in      /Users/yannlaviolette/Sites/finance/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php on line 68
```

( ! )

```
Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: No mapping file found named 'Proxies.__CG__.Entities.Category.dcm.yml' for class 'Proxies\__CG__\Entities\Category'. in /Users/yannlaviolette/Sites/finance/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php on line 68
```

My Mapping Object

```
Entities\FinancialRecord:
   type: entity
   table: finance.financial_record
   fields:
      id:
         id: true
         type: bigint
  nullable: false
  generator:
    strategy: SEQUENCE
transactionId:
  type: string
  length: 255
  fixed: false
  nullable: false
  column: transaction_id
transactionType:
  type: string
  length: 10
  fixed: false
  nullable: false
  column: transaction_type
datePosted:
  type: datetimetz
  nullable: false
  column: date_posted
dateUser:
  type: datetimetz
  nullable: false
  column: date_user
payeeName:
  type: string
  length: 255
  fixed: false
  nullable: false
  column: payee_name
payeeCity:
  type: string
  length: 255
  fixed: false
  nullable: false
  column: payee_city
payeeState:
  type: string
  length: 3
  fixed: false
  nullable: false
  column: payee_state
amount:
  type: decimal
  nullable: false
manyToOne:
   category:
      targetEntity: Entities\Category
      cascade: ["persist", "merge"]
    account:
      targetEntity: Entities\Account
      cascade: ["persist", "merge"]
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

I really have no ideas. Spent 2 days on this problem. Can somebody help me plz!

Yann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have in one project a manyToOne relation.

The only difference I see compared to your yml file is that I don't put `Entities\Category` as targetEntity, but simply `Category`.

**Example of my specific implementation:**

```
manyToOne:
    Order:
        targetEntity: Order
    Product:
        targetEntity: Product
```